# How to list table data from multiple MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql

I have tens of databases in MySQL and all of them have table `log` with the same structure. Is there easy way (one line or couple of lines of SQL) to list data from all of these similar tables in all the databases ? Without the need of writing all the database names ?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you need be able to identify the source database for each line in the resulting output? The databases and tables can be dynamically drawn from `information_schema.TABLES` and used to construct a union query.

Comment: I don't understand why somebody downvotes this question and not even bother tell his reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system table `information_schema.TABLES` holds table information, including the schema (database) which owns the table. You could use that to construct a `UNION ALL` query combining all the `log` tables, through clever concatenation with `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Instead of the default `,` concatenation separator however, you will use a skeletal SQL fragment `UNION ALL SELECT col, col2, col3..` as the separator. The result will be a query that looks like:

```
SELECT col, col2, col3 FROM db1.log 
UNION ALL SELECT col, col2, col3 FROM db2.log
UNION ALL SELECT col, col2, col3 FROM db3.log...
```

The query will be something to the effect of:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.log') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM '))
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'log';
```

The outer `CONCAT()` ensures that the `SELECT cols... FROM` begins the query. The `GROUP_CONCAT()` gathers all the databases together in one line joined by the `UNION ALL` component, and the `CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.log')` qualifies the dynamically retrieved database names with the `log` table name.

It may be tempting to use `SELECT *`, but I would avoid it in case the tables do not all have columns in the same order.

This outputs a complete SQL string which you may then execute in any client.  It would also be possible to place this in the body of a `CREATE PROCEDURE` which creates the string then calls `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` on it. Generally, this takes the form of:

```
SET @qry = 'SELECT CONCAT(\'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM \', GROUP_CONCAT(....'
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Remember that in this context, the SQL is a *string* which must be single-quoted in its entirety, you must backslash escape the quotes within it.

Finally, a note about identifier quoting. The code I have here assumes your database names never require backtick quoting. Depending on how your databases are named, it may be necessary to `CONCAT()` backticks like

```
CONCAT('`', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`')
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I have edited your SQL a bit, to get also the name of each table in one column. It goes like this:
`SELECT CONCAT('SELECT col1, col2, col3, ',  
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', TABLE_SCHEMA , '" AS table_name', ' FROM ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.log') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL SELECT col1, col2, col3, '))
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'log';`